# Keep getting a 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing' when running my app, can't figure out why

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm using the python 3 idle, and it's not highlighting anything to tell me what the syntax error is. Mentions it's in line nine, though I can't see it.

Here's the code, it's a school project for a 'speed checker'

```
import time#python module with time related functions

file = open('speeders.txt', 'r')
speeders = file.read()
print (speeders) #prints out list of speeding cars

reg_plate = int(input("Please enter the car's registration plate"))#registration plate
speed_limit = int(input("Please enter your speed limit in mph"))#assigns speed limit
input("Press enter when the car passes the first sensor")#assign values to the end and start time variables
start_time = time.time()
input("Press enter when the car passes the second sensor")
end_time = time.time()
distance = float(input("Enter the distance between the two sensors in metres")) #assigns a value to distance
time_taken = end_time - start_time #works out the time it took the car to travel the length of the road 

AverageSpeed = distance / time_taken #works out the average speed of the car
print ("The average speed of the car is", AverageSpeed, "m/s") #prints out the average speed of the car in m/s
AverageSpeedMPH = (AverageSpeed *  2.23694) #converts to mph
print ("That's", AverageSpeedMPH, "in mph") #prints out the speed in mph

if AverageSpeedMPH > speed_limit: #prints out whether car is speeding, adds to txt file
    print (reg_plate, "is speeding")
    file = open("speeders.txt", "a")
    file.write(reg_plate + ",")
    file.close()
else:
    print (reg_plate, "is not speeding, be on your merry way") #prints out if not speeding
```

Here's what is displayed when the app runs

```
Please enter the car's registration plate5
Please enter your speed limit in mph5
Press enter when the car passes the first sensor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Szymon\Google Drive\Computing\Actual CA work\app2.py", line 9, in <module>
    input("Press enter when the car passes the first sensor")#lines 3-7 assign values to the end and start time variables
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Check which Python version you're on, and make sure it's the one you're supposed to be on.

Comment: Are you entering text and then hitting enter? Or is "mph5" copy-pasted from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Python2, but still using `input()`.  Try either switching to Python3, or using `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` instead of 'input()'

> If you use input, then the data you type is is interpreted as a Python
>   Expression which means that you end up with gawd knows what type of
>   object in your target variable, and a heck of a wide range of
>   exceptions that can be generated. So you should NOT use input unless
>   you're putting something in for temporary testing, to be used only by
>   someone who knows a bit about Python expressions.

Look here for more. [More Info](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1461_Python-input-v-raw-input.html)